# BingAds Client State, oauth_web_auth_code_grant

Tags: python-3.x, bing-api

I would like to get my custom "Reports" data from my BingAds out with the bingads API. I am using the `KeywordsAds.py` example, which may not be the correct one. However, my problem starts with the authentication, I cannot seem to find all the authentication inputs needed. I am missing examples in like, so I know if I am inserting the right data:

```
authorization_data=AuthorizationData(
    account_id='123456789', --instead of just None
    customer_id='123456789', --instead of just None
    developer_token='12345A1234567891', --instead of just DeveloperTokenGoesHere
    authentication='OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant', --instead of just None
```

)

1) To the code above, what `authentication` do I need to choose for the WebAPI? (2) And for my problem stated, do I need to use a WebAPI, or would a `Web` platform be more useful?

```
CLIENT_ID='ClientIdGoesHere'
CLIENT_STATE='ClientStateGoesHere'
```

3) What is the Client_State? I did google this term, but did not find an explanation. What values could/need to be inserted?

And lastly, I do not find the client_secret and redirection_uri in the example code, but it is stated on the [Getting Started page for Python on Bing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-overview-getting-started-python-with-web-services.aspx):

```
oauth_web_auth_code_grant = OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirection_uri=REDIRECTION_URI
```

Is this necessary to fill in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I have solved the problem some time back.

The first code block is correct, this is how the examples would look like, just replace the numbers in `account_id` and `customer_id`. The `developer_token` has numbers and letters as displayed in my question. For the `authentication`, use `'OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant'`.

To answer question 1: The WebAPI works, (2) and for `CLIENT_ID` use the WebAPI's `Application ID URI`, the part after `api://`.

Q3: The `CLIENT_STATE` I left as is, it is not needed.

The last code block int he question is not needed.

If you are a beginner like me and need some help, I made a quick and dirty Python template. It downloads my report to CSV, then I import it to Pandas where I clean the dataset, then I write it again out to CSV, and finally upload it to Google Analytics [here](https://github.com/ccasimiro9444/my_templates/blob/master/bing_download_to_ga_upload/bing_daily_ga_transfer.py)

Comment: Hey @ccasimiro9444, i know its been a long time since this issue, but i having trouble in running your script. After minimal modifications, I am able to get account details but reports are coming as None. Please suggest

Comment: Hi @Shivanshu, its been too long to remember. but maybe have a look here https://github.com/ccasimiro9444/my_templates/blob/master/bing_download_to_ga_upload/bing_daily_ga_transfer.py

Comment: Hey @ccasimiro9444, seems bingapi is a bit buggy, though after few hit and trials, i got my script working. :)